# Arc/Curve in CSS3 rather than image - border-radius?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I've been given a design (see snippet image) with tabs top and bottom. They begin with a curve. Rather than use a graphic, I'd like to do this with CSS but it **must** be exactly as the design (top curve opposite to bottom curve).

I feel like it's achievable but it might be quite a dirty hack, like a circle inside a div with anything overlapping the div hidden, hmmm. Any CSS whizz kids who can advise?

[image: provided mock-up]

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I think you can make a box with circular edges in css, then color it as the background and place it just on top of the header in z index. rest should be higher in z index. snip the top off a couple of pixes using a positioning, as their curve looks like its a snipped round square.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388078/is-a-concave-border-radius-possible?rq=1

Comment: No it's not a duplicate, it's along the same lines but it's not an even curve or arc like that question. I'd seen that and spent 45 minutes looking around Stack and Googling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a pseudo element:

```css
body {
    background: pink;
}
.someElement {
    background: purple;
    height: 30px;
}

.someElement:before {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 32px;
    background: pink;
    border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="someElement"></div>
```

Comment: This seems very neat/short but why is there a 2px height diff? I can see your example works nicely, having trouble applying it to my context but will persevere.

Comment: That was just to make the curve more similar to your image. Without it the angle wasn't quite right

Comment: Ah ok. It's a great answer, thank you. I now have it working. I can't +1 your answer because someone -1 my question (!) so I'm down in reputation to 13 (I'm newish to Stack) - I will revisit when rep goes up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt - you can play with the width/left/border-radius properties to get the curve perfect.

```css
body {
  background: #F9EDF9;
}

.main {
  background: #7C2A7E;
  height: 75px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.circle {
  background: #F9EDF9;
  border-radius: 48%;
  height: 158px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 118px;
}

.top .circle {
  left: -87px;
  top: -14px;
}
.bottom {
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.bottom .circle {
  left: -87px;
  top: -72px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main top">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>


<div class="main bottom">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Another great answer, bit more mark-up than the psuedo solution but along the lines of what I was thinking but couldn't think how to write. Thanks rmornin.

Answer (score -3):

Nope. That would be a 20px by 10px .png with a curve shape with the same pink background color and the rest of the space is transparent..

You would then applied

```
.nav li:first-child {
    background: xxxxxx
}
.nav li:last-child {
    background: xxxxxx
}
```