# Create radius by css

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying this using border-radius but it doesn't seems like this image.

[image]

Comment: The yellow portion or the black?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388078/is-a-concave-border-radius-possible?s=1|3.4279

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do?  You want your web page element to render so that it looks like your sample image?

Comment: You guys understand me wrong. you see it is a only right side radius. not other side...

Answer (score 0):

set border-radius: 50%;

Below is an example css code for a div

```
div {
height: 500px;
border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
padding: 10px 40px; 
background: yellow;
width: 400px;
border-radius: 0% 50% 50% 0%;
}
```

Comment: It is not radius all side or cycle. it is only one side radius. other side square.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create circle, give same height and width to div and add border-radius property 50%.

```css
.circle{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:#000;
  border-radius:50%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to make the black one a circle then just add the following css code to the class/id of the div. If your trying the whole image then add this css code to that particular id/class.(you can change the height and width if you want.)

```css
#circle{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#000;
  border-radius:100%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```