# shape the corners of the div

Tags: css

I want to bent the corners of the div like a shape of bow!

I tried border-radius but it shapes the corners too much.
Is there a any css3 property to achieve the result?

This is what i've got now

[image]

this is what i want it to look like..

[image]

html:

```
 <body>
   <div class="who_we_are_bg">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="content">

<div class="who_we_are_content">
<img src="images/who-we-are.jpg" alt="LCK chemicals"/>
<div class="corner1"></div>
<div class="corner2"></div>
<div class="corner3"></div>
<div class="corner4"></div>
<h2>WHO WE WRE</h2>
<p>SRI LCK Chemical founded in 2010 has exceptional sourcing ability for chemicals used in Industrial and House keep segments. We strive to develop quality products and outstanding customer service.</p>
<p>SRI LCK Chemical founded in 2010 has exceptional sourcing ability for chemicals used in Industrial and House keep segments. We strive to develop quality products and outstanding customer service.</p>
 <a href="#">more info</a>

  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 </body>
```

css:

```
 .container{max-width:1170px;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid red;}
  .who_we_are_bg{width:100%;float:left;background:url("images/texture2.jpg")repeat 0 0;}
.who_we_are_content {float: none;margin: 0 auto;width: 90%;padding:50px 0 80px;overflow:hidden;}
.who_we_are_content img{margin:8px 40px 20px 0;padding:10px;background:#fff;position:relative;}
.corner1{position:absolute;width:50px;height:10px;  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;z-index:-1;}
.who_we_are_content h2{font-family: 'OpenSans-Bold';font-size:30px;margin:10px 0 10px;}
.who_we_are_content p{padding-bottom:10px;font-family: 'OpenSansSemibold';}
.who_we_are_content a{font-family: 'OpenSansSemibold';text-decoration:none;float:left;padding:10px;background:#98b769;color:#fff;}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388078/is-a-concave-border-radius-possible

Comment: You need a half border or what ?

Comment: yes dude..like shown in the figure

Answer (score 0):

You can give the impression of a concave border using radial gradients on the background. For example, something like this:

```
#test {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #888888;
    background:
      radial-gradient(circle 20px at -20% 50%,transparent,transparent 100px,#888888 100px),
      radial-gradient(circle 20px at 120% 50%,transparent,transparent 100px,#888888 100px);
    background-size:100px 200px, 100px 200px;
    background-position:0 0,100% 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Note that most webkit browsers still require prefixes for radial-gradients, and if you want to fully support older browsers you may need to implement the older gradient syntax too.

Referred from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16388187/4119808

Comment: it gives rounded edges! but i want edges to be straight and little protruded in the middle,as shown the image