# how to deform element from top and bottom

Tags: html, css

Is there any way in `css` to deform the element from top and bottom as shown in below image? I don't wanna use `background-image` for this.

[image]

Comment: you want a concave shape?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388078/is-a-concave-border-radius-possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.box {
  background: #363742;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  border-radius: 1000px / 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  content: '';
  right: -50px;
  left: -50px;
  top: -50px;
}

.box:after {
  bottom: -50px;
  top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Very nice - better than my answer!