# how to make transition ellipse in css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-shapes

So, I have sidebar that just display some of its content, when it hovered it will display all the sidebar width.

this is the CSS code:

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding-top: 20px;
    transition: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
    opacity: 0.8;
    box-shadow: 0px 20px 50px black; 
} 
.sidenav:hover{
    width: 215px;
    transition: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

my question is how to make the transition of my sidebar become ellipse first then display the full width. thanks before

this is the illustration:
[image: the initial state][image: final state][image: what I mean state]

Comment: post your full code in JSfiddle or codepen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with only a simple transition effect. You will need to use [CSS keyframe animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) to achieve a border radius only on the width transition:

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  transition: 0.8s;
  opacity: 0.8;
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 50px black;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: black;
}

.sidenav:hover {
  width: 215px;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: roundborder;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes roundborder {
    0%   { border-radius: 0; }
    50%  { border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0; }
    100% { border-radius: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav"></div>
```

Of course you need proper vendor prefixes for older browser support. See [border-radius on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) for more information.

Comment: I mean the radius will change when the process of changing width from 100px to 215px, but when already 215px it back to normal

Comment: Ok, updated my answer. You need keyframe animation for this.

Comment: hey, how I make the border is concave? is it possible?

Comment: It's possible, look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388078/is-a-concave-border-radius-possible).