# How to make concave animation with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

So, I have sidebar that just display some of its content, when it hovered it will display all the sidebar width.

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  transition: 0.8s;
  opacity: 0.8;
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 50px black;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: black;
}

.sidenav:hover {
  width: 215px;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: roundborder;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes roundborder {
    0%   { border-radius: 0; }
    50%  { border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0; }
    100% { border-radius: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav"></div>
```

my question is how to make concave animation if the sidebar is not hover? so after it hovered and the pointer not in sidebar again, it will back to the initial state but with concave animation, I cant use the negative percent, so what do I use for it? thanks

Comment: Related: [Is a concave border radius possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388078/is-a-concave-border-radius-possible)

Comment: but my question is in animation, just like my example. I will use it on `.sidenav` @MatheusAvellar

Comment: I'd recommend something along the lines of what [tessi](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16388799/4824627) said, using `::before` and `::after` to simulate a concave border. You could adapt it to use in an animation as well

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have to do with **SVG** you create a normal square and then two

animation the first when it's out with rounded corner then the second is with

concave corner.

Comment: I'm so sorry for late reply, but why I mean is, when roundborder-in is active the shape is concave not convex too

Comment: Ok , i think that it's not possible like this you have to create an **SVG** and animate it , i think that the only way

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question but can you not just put the same animations on the div (without :hover). Like this:

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  transition: 0.8s;
  opacity: 0.8;
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 50px black;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: black;
  animation-name: roundborder2;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

.sidenav:hover {
  width: 215px;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: roundborder;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes roundborder {
    0%   { border-radius: 0; }
    50%  { border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0; }
    100% { border-radius: 0; }
}
@keyframes roundborder2 {
    0%   { border-radius: 0; }
    50%  { border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0; }
    100% { border-radius: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav"></div>
```